# Naming recommendation about "set"

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, naming

I have trouble with making proper variable name

I made some variable like "node_set_name"

but this name looks not good for me because my program uses a lot of get set functions

maybe this feeling just comes from my first language is not English...

anyway, can anyone recommend me some good variable name for replacing mathematics mean of "set"?

I think I can use "group" rather than "set"
node_group_name but I am not sure this "group" has replace meaning of "set" naturally?

```
typedef struct {
uint8* node_set_name;                      
uint8 node_set_type;                        
uint8 related_node_information;               
uint8 element_set_count;                    
uint8 _pad;
uint8 node_element_list[MAX_MISC_NODE_SET_SIZE]; 
} fsw_misc_node_set_information;
```

Comment: What about "collection"? It is the standard generic name for objects representing/holding multiple items.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I will consider it, Thank you